# Herramientas para crear una extensión web para Firefox en base a selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-webextensions, extensiones

Estoy en eso de desarrollar una extensión para Firefox algo parecido a esta extensión [Web Scraper - Free Web Scraping](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper-free-web-scra/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn), y se me ocurre que puedo hacer algo como con [SELENIUM](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) y python para manipular el DOM del navegador, etc. Si me pueden recomendar qué herramientas de desarrollo es necesario aprender para construir algo así?, gracias